# View multiple Mamp Pro websites on local network

Tags: apache, port, mamp, lan

Using Mamp Pro 2.1.1 I have 3 Wordpress websites running that I would like to view via mobile devices (iPhone, iPad, etc.) for testing AND allow for my team to edit simultaneously before publishing live over my office LAN.

By appending port 8888 to my IP (`mylocalIP:8888`) I can access the first website via phone or other computer. However I have not been able to figure out how to view any of the other websites easily.

I have tried setting different port numbers for each of the other websites which all, rather than going where I want, redirect to the `mylocalIP:8888` which is quite frustrating.

[image: Screen of port settings]

What I'm looking for is something simple like `mylocalIP:5555` to go to the correct website. What I'm not looking for is installing another program and/or tweaking settings on every persons computer that is working on the website or wants to preview/approve it.

Any thoughts? I've read of the possibility of an Apache conflict from the native Mac and MAMP installations, could this be the problem? I am running OSX 10.8.2 if that helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully used at setup which includes the name of my computer, e.g. myMacBookPro.

In your case it would look like this:

1. IP / Port = * / 5555
2. Add 'theNameOfYourComputer.local' as alias (e.g. myMacBookPro.local)
3. Other persons on your LAN should now be able to access your site via http://theNameOfYourComputer.local:5555

Hope it works for you.